# Re-Run Event in VB.NET Windows Forms

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have an windows form with a combobox, a button, and a datagridview.

The user selects one predefined value from the combobox, then they will click the button.
The code executes, and it will fill the datagridview. Everything works ok.

My goal is to re-run automatically the click event (with the same selection from the combobox) at every 15 minutes, for a period of time (this period is defined by me).

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Have a look here [ask] .. cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a timer

```
Dim WithSelected As Boolean = False
    Dim selectedValue As String
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        selectedValue = ComboBox1.SelectedText
        'Load_DataGridView()
        WithSelected = True

    End Sub
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        If WithSelected = True Then

            'Set timer interval to 900000
            'Load_DataGridView()

        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! (I forgot to set the Timer1 property **Enable=True**)

Comment: @MariusT Might I suggest a slight improvement to your answer? Separate the code that the OP would put in your 'Load_datagridView into its own private Sub and then call the sub from both the click event and the timer tick. That way, if the code needs changing, only one edit is needed on one piece of code rather than two  edits that must be identical.

Comment: That was the first thing I did! Thanks for your sugesstion !